# Querying for data attributes with backslashes

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

I have an HTML data attribute with a backslash in the value. A naive query for this element fails; I have to use double backslashes in the query.

Consider the following test:

```js
var file = "foo\\bar"; // That's a single backslash, to be clear.
document.getElementById('d2').dataset.file = file;

var singleBackslash = '*[data-file="'+file+'"]';
var doubleBackslash = '*[data-file="'+file.replace(/\\/g,'\\\\')+'"]';

var singleCount = document.querySelectorAll(singleBackslash).length;
var doubleCount = document.querySelectorAll(doubleBackslash).length;

var out = document.querySelector('textarea');
out.value  = "There are "+singleCount+" elements matching "+singleBackslash+"\n";
out.value += "There are "+doubleCount+" elements matching "+doubleBackslash;
```

```html
<div data-file="foo\bar"></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
<textarea cols="60"></textarea>
```

On Chrome v48.0.2564.109m on Win7x64 the result is:

```
There are 0 elements matching *[data-file="foo\bar"]
There are 2 elements matching *[data-file="foo\\bar"]
```

I cannot find any HTML spec that requires this behavior. Is the double-backslash required on all browsers? What specification describes this?

Comment: FWIW, the same behavior occurs if I use jQuery to search for the element; however, this may only indicate that jQuery is falling back to the browser's native `querySelectorAll` implementation instead of Sizzle.

Comment: The ` \ ` is a special character and needs to be escaped; it is also the escape character.  In your example ` \b ` would translate to only `b`. If you wanted to use the ` \ ` as a character, you would have to escape it, thus ` \\ `

Comment: @vol7ron I have already sufficiently escaped it in JavaScript. It has no special meaning in an HTML5 attribute. I have not yet found any mention of backslashes in the specifications for `querySelectorAll`. I understand what it means to escape characters; can you point to which specification gives special meaning to backslash in this context?

Comment: It's for strings, in general, in ECMAScript.  You're using JS, so it's not just HTML5.  [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String); it looks like I was wrong regarding `\b`, it does have a translation (to a backspace); in regex, it would be a word boundary.  For more information on Query Selector syntax; see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Notes

Comment: The second link (MDN) contains links to the API specs.  Apologies for the first comment; I didn't look at the post's author - pretty sure you already know about escaping.

Comment: yeah, it's messy. deal with it. ;) you think that's bad, look at special chars in `:after`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Selectors API Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/) specification states that `querySelectorAll` accepts a "selector string" which is:

> …a list of one or more **[group of selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-css3-selectors-20110929/)**…

The Selectors Level 3 specification that it links to says:

> Characters in Selectors can be escaped with a backslash according to the same [escaping rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters) as CSS.

Finally, the CSS2.1 specification that it links to describes the three ways that a backslash may be used to escape content.

Thus, `querySelectorAll`—separate from any usage inside of JavaScript—applies special meaning to backslashes.

Comment: So there's a twofold translation.  I created a wrapper function for this, or for a regex pattern generator, which made it a little cleaner to work with mass translations.  Though, it would be nice to see this information in a linter, debug notice, or development tool